# [Unity]Avoid boucing when ground move down

Tags: unity, physics

I have a sphere & a quad, when the quad move down, the sphere fall after and bounce back continuously. I dont want to change my project setting like bounciness, gravity,mass and I need the sphere to move freely to jump between quad.
How can I do this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the physics material of your sphere (or quad, depends on which one makes more sense) in order to remove the bounciness.

If you want to achieve an effect that would not normally be possible in the real life (as in following a moving platform without inertia) you will need an extra layer that will manage this between the two shapes, working closely with the Unity physics engine.

The physics material documentation is here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html

If you want to get more information on this topic you will need to extend your question with a demo of what is happening (video would work) and some info about the object configurations (what components are you using and so on).

Answer (score 0):

not sure how your gravity works in unity but in our jump and run we did years ago we checked if the player touched a moving platform and glued him on it unless the player jumps again. you could do this calling the physic system manually until the player touches the platform again or you just add the player in your scene graph to the platform. it was a very simple game though and didn't use any other physical simulation other than falling down.

Comment: I think you get me wrong, Imagine you in an elevator with a ball, if you drop it itll bounce back but then it going to stay still unless your elevator is free falling